# Find Galois group of $L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I would like to find the Galois group of the field extension $L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})$ and $\zeta_{20}$ is a primitive 20th root of unity (in $\mathbb{C}$).

We know that the Galois group must be of order four, as $L:\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})\subset L$, so $L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is Galois, and $[L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})]=\frac{[L:\mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}):\mathbb{Q})]}=\frac{8}{2}=4$, and if $H=\textrm{Gal}(L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}))$, then $|H|=[L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})]$, so it must be isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$. (Note: $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(20)=8$, where $\phi$ denotes the Euler phi-function)

I have thus far managed to show that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{20})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{4},\zeta_5)=\mathbb{Q}(i)(\zeta_{5})$, and hence that $L:\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is a cyclic field extension of degree four, $\textit{i.e.}\ \textrm{Gal}(L:\mathbb{Q}(i))\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$. I have also noticed that as we may let $\zeta_5=e^{\frac{2}{5}\pi i}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}+10}$, we can express $L$ as: $L=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2\sqrt{5}+10})$.

My initial idea was to let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{-5})$, so that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})\subset K\subset L$, and note that $\textrm{Gal}(L:K)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\textrm{Gal}(K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and thus somehow conclude that $\textrm{Gal}(L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2^2$, which I suspect to be the right conclusion. But this reasoning is of course not only erroneous but unsubstantiated.

I subsequently seemed to become unable to come up with better ideas and thus decided to consult the community.

All help or input would, as always, be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta = \zeta_{20}$. The automorphism $\sigma(\zeta) = \zeta^3$ generates a subgroup of $G = \textrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then the Galois group of $L/L^{\sigma}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by the Galois correspondence. We show that $L^{\sigma} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. Let
$$z = \zeta + \zeta^3 + \zeta^7 + \zeta^9$$
so that $z$ is fixed by $\sigma$. One checks that
$$z + \overline{z} = 2\cos(\pi/10) + 2\cos(3\pi/10) + 2\cos(7\pi/10) + 2\cos(9\pi/10) = 0$$
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
z\overline{z} &= 4 + 2\cos(\pi/5) + \cos(2\pi/5) + 2\cos(3\pi/5) + \cos(4\pi/5) \\
&= 4 + 2\cos(\pi/5) + 2\cos(3\pi/5) \\
&= 5.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
From this we conclude that $L^{\sigma} = \mathbb{Q}(z) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$, thus the Galois group of $L/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\mathbf Q(\zeta_{20})$ and $K=\mathbf Q (\sqrt {-5})$. Here is a "Galois only" argument showing that $Gal( L/K)\cong C_4$. Because $<\zeta_{20}>=<\zeta_4>\times <\zeta_5>, L=\mathbf Q(i,\zeta_5)$ = the compositum of the two linearly disjoint extensions $\mathbf Q(i)$ and $\mathbf Q(\zeta_5)$ over $\mathbf Q$, so $Gal(L/\mathbf Q)\cong C_2\times C_4$, with $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(\zeta_5))\cong C_2$ and $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(i)\cong C_4$. Since the maximal qotient of $C_2\times C_4$ killed by $2$ is $C_2\times C_2$, it follows that $L$ contains exactly $3$ quadratic subfields. What are they ?  Because $5\equiv 1$ mod $4$, the quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_5)$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$ **(*)**, hence our 3 quadratic subfields are $\mathbf Q (i), \mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$ and $K$. Because $K$ and  $\mathbf Q(\zeta_5)$ are linearly disjoint over $\mathbf Q, Gal(L/K)\cong C_4$, just as the case was for $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(i))$. Whereas $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5))\cong C_2\times C_2$ because $L$ is the compositum of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_5)$ and $\mathbf Q(i,\sqrt 5)$ over $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$.

**(*)** This is a classical result coming from the calculation of discriminants. Given an odd prime $p$, put $p^*=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$ ; then the unique quadratic subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p})$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {p^*})$. The statement of your OP can be directly generalized as follows : let $L=\mathbf Q(\zeta_{4p})=\mathbf Q(i,\zeta_p)$, with Galois group $C_2\times C_{p-1}$ ; the $3$ quadratic subfields of $L$ are $\mathbf Q (i), \mathbf Q(\sqrt {p^*})$ and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-p^*})$, with $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(i))\cong Gal(L/\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-p^*}))\cong C_{p-1}$ and $Gal(L/\mathbf Q(\sqrt {p^*}))\cong C_2\times C_{(p-1)/2}$  ./.